# create Attribute from other Attribute names

Tags: database, pivot, rapidminer

I use Read CSV to get the data.
The Data is in this format

```
Country   2013   2014   2015
USA       4      5      8
UK        2      6      3
France    3      7      5
```

I want to convert it to

```
Country   Year   New Attribute
USA       2013   4
USA       2014   5
USA       2015   8
UK        2013   2
UK        2014   6
UK        2015   3
France    2013   3
France    2014   7
France    2015   5
```

pleases tell me how to do this in Rapid Miner in details because I know where little about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `De-Pivot` operator is required for this. Assuming you have regular attributes with these names.

```
Country, 2013, 2014, 2015
```

Connect a `De-Pivot` operator to your example data and configure it as follows.

Within the `attribute name` parameter dialog of the `De-Pivot` operator, set the `attribute name` to be

```
New attribute
```

and set the `attributes` of `attribute name` to

```
([0-9]+)
```

Also in the `De-Pivot` operator, set the `index` attribute to be

```
Year
```

and finally set the `create nominal index` check box to true.

Comment: Someone downvoted this - perhaps they could give some feedback?

Answer (score -2):

Look for meta-data information. or parameter "first_row_as_names" in read_csv method if first row is of attribute names.

check out the documentation here :
http://docs.rapidminer.com/studio/operators/import/data/read_csv.html

Comment: This does not answer the original question.